# Analytical solve for biharmonic equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to analytical Solve or numerical solve by *Mathematica* a biharmonic equation with homogeneous boundary conditions homogeneous?

I considered its solution using Fourier analysis, which is not responsive and its convergence speed is low and can not be used.

$$\nabla^4 U=f(x,y);\,\,U=\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}=0,\,\,\,at\,\, x=0,1;U=\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial y^2}=0,\,\,at\,\, y=0,1$$

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: It seems you could expand both $U$ and $f$ as $\sin(\pi p x ) \sin(\pi q y)$. then the $\nabla^4 U_{pq}$ yields $\pi ^4 \left(p^2+q^2\right)^2 U_{pq}$

Comment: 1. You should write more details about the domain in which you solve this equation. Is it a square?
2. Independently of this you should make a trivial substitution: introduce a new variable V(x,y) equal to the Laplacian of U(x,y). For this variable your equation will be harmonic, non-homogeneous with zero boundary conditions. 
3. Then you solve the next harmonic, non-homogeneous equation. 
4. If the domain is a square, this is easily done without Mathematica.

Comment: I trasformation rectangular domain to normalize domail [0 1]*[0 1]. if I want solve by mathematica, how to solve this problem

Comment: Please respond why the linked topic does not help with your case. And please do not delete the question once it is marked a duplicate. If you provide information that makes it distinct, it will be reopened.

Comment: Your question is an exact duplicate of the linked post in my eyes. If you have difficulty in understanding the solution there, feel free to ask.

Comment: @ xzczd  The question posed on the site (mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135893/2d-inhomogeneous-biharmonic-equation) about the code is not usable and understandable to me. I want a solution expression